# Does snipe allow for multiple successive ranged sneak attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, rogue, ranged-attack, sneak-attack

If I have a rogue who fires a ranged weapon as a sneak attack, then passes his stealth-20 check to snipe, can he then make a second ranged sneak attack on the next round?  If so (or if not), what is the justification?  I haven't been able to find anything that makes this point clear, but the two opinions I have found seem to be:

1. Yes, because the rogue is still hidden
2. No, because the enemy is no longer surprised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, the RAW answer is no. You can snipe and remain hidden, but your next attack is not a sneak attack because "stealthed" isn't a condition that makes a target [flat-footed](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/combat.html#flat-footed) or denies it its Dex bonus to AC. Similarly, if you simply stay hidden until the battle is raging and try to shoot someone, it's not RAW a sneak attack. (It's not because it doesn't say it is, the rules are clear in omission.)

Of course this tends to defy reason, so I let people get in sneak attacks in other situations, as "it's the first round of a combat" is not a real in-game-world thing.

The devs understand the stealth rules are a big hot mess; in fact they posted [some playtest new stealth rules on paizo.com](http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/tags/stealth) in an attempt to come up with something less wonky.

Answer (score 3):

[Sniping on SRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/stealth.html#_stealth)
Action: Usually none. Normally, you make a Stealth check as part of movement, so it doesn't take a separate action. However, using Stealth immediately after a ranged attack (see Sniping, above) is a move action.

Since you spend a move action on the stealth check (and presumably a standard on the attack itself) you cannot full attack. so one attack per round

Edit: In following rounds, assuming the enemy is still hasn't spotted you you can still land sneak attacks since the opponent can't see you, works like invisibility or similar situations